# jQuery Issue not working

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and learning. For some odd reasons the following code doesn't work (I am using Coda2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#click").click(function () {
            $("p").slideToggle("slow");
        });   
    </script>   
</head>

<body>

    <p>Choose Your Language</p>
    <button id="click">Click Me</button>

</body>
    </html>
```

Any help

Comment: If you are new, then you should read the [jQuery tutorial](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/). It explains how the get started with jQuery. Also [learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners), it's indispensable  for solving problems yourself.

Comment: The added twist here is the missing http: or https: from the cdn

Answer (score 5):

Wrap with a document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#click").click(function () {
        $("p").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

[**Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Anton, thanks, but still didn't resolve the issue

Comment: @Abdulla: Well, what **is** the issue? You didn't mention what  the problem actually is, so people jump on the first issue they see. If you want better help, provide useful information. FYI, the solution works exactly how *I* expect it to: http://jsfiddle.net/tPquE/.

Comment: @FelixKling the issue that the code is not working (i.e.: not toggling the text).

Comment: the second issue was file://ajax... see @Jim Cote's solution

Comment: @Abdulla: If the URL scheme really is the problem, then you should have gotten an error in the console, something like `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. For future questions, please add the error messages you get. See the link in [my other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615466/jquery-issue-not-working/18615504#comment27401236_18615466) for more information.

Comment: @mplungjan file://ajax was copied from google library (https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide)

Comment: @FelixKling I got no error for the url

Comment: @mplungjan & FelixKling thank you both, but I added http:, and it is now working

Answer (score 2):

1. If you test from your harddisk instead of a server, use a fully qualified URL to the js file. That is, add `http:` otherwise `file:` will be prepended
2. Wait until the document is loaded before running your script:

   ```
   $(function () {
       $("#click").click(function () {
           $("p").slideToggle("slow");
       });  
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

What Anton said. Or:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<p>Choose Your Language</p>
<button id="click">Click Me</button>
<script>
    $("#click").click(function () {
        $("p").slideToggle("slow");
    });   
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```